# std::equal_range with a permutation

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, permutation

I am trying to use `std::equal_range` to find equal elements in a vector that has been sorted using a separate index array. For some reason, `std::equal_range` cannot find the element.

This is an example.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct compare {
  bool operator()(float value, int index) const { return value < values[permutation[index]]; }
  bool operator()(int index, float value) const { return values[permutation[index]] < value; }
  const std::vector<float>& values;
  const std::vector<int>& permutation;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<float> values = { 1., 2., 2., 4., 6., 5. };
  std::vector<int> permutation = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4 };

  const auto p = std::equal_range(permutation.begin(), permutation.end(), 6., compare{values, permutation});
  for (auto i = p.first; i != p.second; ++i) {
    std::cout << *i << '\n';
  }
}
```

I expect that the index to value 6 is printed. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Well, the first point [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) requires that "all elements for which the expression is true precedes all elements for which the expression is false". It doesn't seems the case: https://godbolt.org/z/ns5ME3bbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've confused your indexing.  `permutation.begin()` and `permutation.end()` will return the values of `permutation`, so when you use those values in your comparator, it's not what you expect.  e.g.  `permutation.begin()` points to 0, indicating the first element of the values vector.  However, when you use it in the comparison, you're using it to index into the permutation vector (again)

Replace `values[permutation[index]` in the compare operator with `values[index]`

Answer (score 0):

The values that get passed to the comparator are the elements of `permuatation` not indices into `permutation`. If you change the comparator accordingly you get the expected result:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct compare {
  bool operator()(float value, int index) const { return value < values[index]; }
  bool operator()(int index, float value) const { return values[index] < value; }
  const std::vector<float>& values;
  const std::vector<int>& permutation;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<float> values = { 1., 2., 2., 4., 6., 5. };
  std::vector<int> permutation = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 4 };

  const auto p = std::equal_range(permutation.begin(), permutation.end(), 6., compare{values, permutation});
  for (auto i = p.first; i != p.second; ++i) {
    std::cout << *i << '\n';
  }
}
```

This will print `4` because `values[permutation[5]] == values[4] == 6.`.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/za54GYWrq)